# Python - 're.sub'ed string still contains special characters when put into sqlalchemy db.execute command

Tags: python, regex, postgresql, sqlalchemy

In the search route of my flask webapp, I want to remove special characters from the user input (q) before searching it up in my PostgreSQL database:

```
q = re.sub('[?*()+[]+', '', q)

search_results = db.execute("SELECT name WHERE name SIMILAR TO :q",{"q": q+'%'})
```

Unfortunately something still seems to go wrong, and I keep getting a DataError from sqlalchemy. E.g. when I input '?', I get:

> sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (psycopg2.errors.InvalidRegularExpression) invalid regular expression: quantifier operand invalid
>
> [SQL: SELECT name WHERE name SIMILAR TO %(q)s]
>
> [parameters: {'q': '?%'}]
>
> (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/9h9h)

The parameters suggest that the value of q is still '?', but when I try removing special characters with `re.sub()` in the terminal, it successfully removes any special character I want:

```
>>> import re
>>> q = '?'
>>> q = re.sub('[?*()+[]+', '', q)
>>> q
''
```

Besides that, queries with accepted characters are successfully searched up.

Where lies the problem and how do I fix this?

Comment: This is a good start, but please provide the actual code that fails to sanitize the query string, not just separate lines of code, while still keeping it minimal (we don't necessarily need your whole controller / view function). Reading the help on [mcve] is a good thing to do at this point.

Comment: It is usually recommended to use rawstrings while using regex, such as:

    `re.sub(r'[?*()+[]+', '', q)`

Comment: @RHP yeah I tried with and without rawstrings mulitple times but neither worked

Answer (score 0):

Rebooting the flask server fixed it, even though I normally don't need to do this after changes.